# libtinfo6 library is not installable

Tags: dependencies, linux-mint

I am trying to install iraf and getting the error below. How to solve that, please?

https://github.com/iraf-community/x11iraf

```
sudo apt install gcc make bison flex libncurses-dev tcl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
bison is already the newest version (2:3.0.4.dfsg-1build1).
flex is already the newest version (2.6.4-6).
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1ubuntu1).
tcl-dev is already the newest version (8.6.0+9).
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xgterm : Depends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Which OS and which version do you use? It seems that you have xgterm already installed as a package, why would you try to install x11iraf again?

Comment: And did you do the "Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages"?

Comment: `apt --fix-broken install` gives only some option. I am using Linux Mint 19.2. When I wrote `xgterm`, I obtain `xgterm: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` - it is the reason I am trying to install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mint 19.2 does not have xgterm, so this was probably installed from somewhere else and therefore causing problems. Installing packages from different distributions is never a good idea.

The simple solution is to remove xgterm with

```sh
sudo apt remove xgterm
```